# How to setup Ruby on Rails with Neo4j database on Macbook M1? Ruby 2.7.7 and Rails 5.2.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, graph-databases, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.7

I've been trying to setup Neo4j in my existing Rails project which has Rails version 5.2.8.1 and Ruby 2.7.7

I've gone through almost every documentation i could find and had long chats with ChatGPT but nothing has worked so far.

I'm trying to run Neo4j with Docker.

My docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=512m
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j/data:/data
      - ./neo4j/logs:/logs
```

I've tried various combinations of settings with neo4j.yml, neo4j.conf and application.rb
Nothing has worked unfortunately.

If anyone can help me with steps to setup even a new Rails app with ruby 2.7.7 and with any recent version of Neo4j, that'll be immensely helpful !!

Docker works. I can run graph database and run cypher queries in the browser. But from rails, it doesn't work.

The most i could get to was being able to run a MATCH query but when it came to creating nodes or running neo4j:migrate command, it didn't work at all.